# Using the Snaptoroad API with Premium plan

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to setup an application that consumes the snaptoroad api. I have been given details of the premium plan and I have the client id and the crypto code.

I have tried to generate  the signature using the form below

[Form to get signature using client id and crypto code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrpCp.png)

But it throws the error saying that I works for maps.googleapis and not for roads.googleapis (which is a the snaproad api). I used a pyton program to generate the signature, that did return an URL with the signature but that does not work. The web document on for snaptoroad only shows the APIKey option. But my organisation has a premium plan and i want to use that so that I can test the product better.

Need help with this. I have limited experience in using the map APIs.

Regards
Vaishak

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Roads API supports authorization by API key, the client ID and digital signature are not supported in Roads API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/get-api-key

You should generate an API key in your Premium plan project and use it in your requests.

You can figure out what is your project number in the support portal. Click Maps: Usage Report on the left and you will see something like:

gme-[company] & proj-[number] ([type])

The [number] is your Premium plan project number. If you don't know who has access to the Premium plan project, reach out to Google maps technical support team.

Hope it helps!